# plot logistic regression line over heat plot

Tags: r, logistic, data-visualization

My data is binary with two linear independent variables.  For both predictors, as they get bigger, there are more positive responses.  I have plotted the data in a heatplot showing density of positive responses along the two variables.  There are the most positive responses in the top right corner and negative responses in the bottom left, with a gradient change visible along both axes.

I would like to plot a line on the heatplot showing where a logistic regression model predicts that positive and negative responses are equally likely.  (My model is of the form `response~predictor1*predictor2+(1|participant)`.)

My question: How can I figure out the line based on this model at which the positive response rate is 0.5?

I tried using predict(), but that works the opposite way; I have to give it values for the factor rather than giving the response rate I want.  I also tried using a function that I used before when I had only one predictor (`function(x) ((log(x/(1-x)))-fixef(fit)[1])/fixef(fit)[2]`), but I can only get single values out of that, not a line, and I can only get values for one predictor at a time.

I am using R.

Edit: I have added a contour plot over the heat plot (using geom_contour in ggplot2), which produces this:

[image: Each cell represents the frequency of positive responses for a single stimulus. I added the numbers for clarity.]

I'd like to have a line that actually predicts the cutoff point in a fine-grained way; right now for the independent variables I have stimuli at points 40, 45, 50, etc. but I would like to see a line that predicts, e.g., that when x=32 and y=36 that's the threshold for 50% positive responses.  It could be a curve or it could even be a straight line (whose slope might help visualise the relative contributions of the two factors), but I'm not looking for a pure description of the cells which are >50 vs <50, which is what I think this is doing, I'm looking for a way to plot the regression's predictions.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are using glm(), and you are interacting the two predictors on purpose?

Comment: Although discussed in terms of R, I think this Q isn't about programming.

Comment: Are you asking about a contour plot?

Comment: @robin.datadrivers I am using glmer() and I am interacting them on purpose although the effect of the interaction is marginal I think it makes sense to expect possible interaction here.

Comment: @gung Sorry, does this mean I should post it elsewhere or something?

Comment: @Glen_b Maybe? I guess I've only seen contour plot when it makes basically concentric "circles"; does it make sense to use one when I only want a single line and it won't be a circle? Can this be overlaid over a heat plot (I mean both is it technically possible and it is good practice)?  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: No, @emily. I'm arguing that your Q is on-topic here.

Comment: @Glen_b Okay, so I got the contour to overlay over the heat plot with ggplot2, but it doesn't produce a fit-type line; the line sort of doubles back on itself if that makes sense?

Comment: Can you show it? Why would it be a line?

Comment: @Glen_b I added it above (sorry it's huge). I also tried to explain above why I think I want a line, but let me know if it doesn't make sense.  Thank you very much!

Comment: My intent wasn't that you plot a contour plot of the data, but (in effect) a contour plot of the model fit.